# how to popup image after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, popup, w2ui

In my code, there is a lot of image in a table. I want to click a photo & then the photo will popup in a large size. But I do not have much idea about javascript & jquery. I try to do this but do not work. can u please tell me where is the wrong or give me a proper code for popup image after click.

my header link is below. is there need any other link to be added??

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

here is html part:

```
<div>
    <td> <img class="btn" onclick="popup()" style="width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:4px;" src="upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>"></img></td>
</div>
```

here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popup() {
        w2popup.open({
            title: 'Image',
            body: '<div class="w2ui-centered"><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>"></img></div>'
        });
    }
</script>
```

there is a problem in my script. it popup a box but dont show the picture. can  anyone please help me how to show image in the pop up box. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you find any error in console ?

Comment: By "popup" do you mean that you want the image to grow bigger over the other images? If so, I have a good solution in css3

Comment: pagecreate event is a jquery mobile event

Comment: and the form of the on function is something new to me

Comment: no there is no error in console @Rayon can u provide me another solution if u know?

Comment: yes, after click,the image will popup in large size over the screen. do u have any solution? @Roysh

Comment: I have an elegant code that will make the image larger on hover, but not on click, is that good for you?

Comment: no I have to popup any image after click :(

Comment: please everyone have a look in my code.. I edited it. now can u plz help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to popup image over the screen after clicking the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826471/how-to-popup-image-over-the-screen-after-clicking-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

1. I tried it using Node.js and EJS template – it works perfectly on PC browsers but not on mobile.
2. Make sure that this link works correctly in an `img` element, `"upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>"`

Comment: upload/<?php echo $row['image'];?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).